# TalkBack handles `view.requestFocus()` inconsistently across devices

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

We’ve learned that TalkBack handles `view.requestFocus()` inconsistently across devices. What we found:

Accessibility announcements set with

```
 view.announceForAccessibility(“Please enter a valid email address”)
 view.requestFocus()
```

are not announced all devices.

When `requestFocus()` is called:

For four devices, TalkBack announces the view that requested focus, then announces "Please enter a valid email address”, which is how we expect it to work.

But, two devices announce the view that requested focus, and ignore "Please enter a valid email address". I tried every approach to force TalkBack to announce "Please enter a valid email address" on the two devices that don’t work properly, but nothing works. I firmly believe this is a bug in either the Android Framework or, more likely, with TalkBack because the same situation shouldn't be announced differently on different devices.

I tested this issue on six devices, including:

- OS-wise:

  - Four run Android 8.0.0 = Two work, and two don’t
  - Two run Android 8.1.0 = Both work
- Brand-wise:

  - Two LG = Both work
  - One Google Pixel = Works
  - One Samsung = Doesn’t work
  - One Motorola = Doesn’t work
  - One Nexus = Works
- Two were emulators (both work), and the remainder were physical devices (two of five work).

Comment: Hey, I am facing similar issue, did you find any resolution ?

Comment: Unfortunately not